# Sending UDP Broadcast for populating USR-TCP232 LAN Modules information

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, broadcast

I am using USR-TCP232 LAN Modules for an embedded project.
I have a tool to query those modules made by the manufacturer, it works great.
But, I want it in my code in C#. So, I decided to make one for myself. I believe I am so close but I guess a small glitch which gives me hard times and I need somebody to put some shed light on.

I can send a UDP broadcast and I can observe the traffic via "WireShark".
It is quite similar with the original tool. But, I can't receive the answered data sent by the devices on the network in my code.

**Console application in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace UDPer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UDPer udp = new UDPer();
            udp.Starter();

            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            do
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                    switch (cki.KeyChar)
                    {
                        case 's':
                            udp.Send("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789");

                            break;
                        case 'x':
                            udp.Stop();
                            return;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            } while (true);
        }
    }

    class UDPer
    {
        private Socket udpSock;
        private byte[] buffer;
        public void Starter()
        {
            //Setup the socket and message buffer
            udpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
            udpSock.EnableBroadcast = true;
            buffer = new byte[1024];

             udpSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            //udpSock.ExclusiveAddressUse = false; // only if you want to send/receive on same machine.

             //The socket must not be bound or connected.
            //Start listening for a new message.
            EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                udpSock.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopped listening");
            }
            catch { /* don't care */ }

        }
        private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get the received message.
                Socket recvSock = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
                recvSock.EnableBroadcast = true;
                EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                int msgLen = recvSock.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
                byte[] localMsg = new byte[msgLen];
                Array.Copy(buffer, localMsg, msgLen);

                //Start listening for a new message.
                EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock);

                //Handle the received message
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved {0} bytes from {1}:{2}",
                                  msgLen,
                                  ((IPEndPoint)clientEP).Address,
                                  ((IPEndPoint)clientEP).Port);
                //Do other, more interesting, things with the received message.
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(localMsg);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0} ", message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //expected termination exception on a closed socket.
            }
        }

        public void Send(string message)
        {
            UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(1500);
            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 1500);
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            udp.Send(data, data.Length, ipEndPoint);
            udp.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Wireshark capture**

[image]

**Note that:** This Wireshark capture is exactly the same as the original tool does.

**Some definitions:**

My PC where C# application resides: 192.168.65.82

LAN Module IP Address: 192.168.65.8

Ports must be 1500 which is all OK.

Send payload for querying LAN Modules;
"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"

So, I have tried tons of different options one by one but no jo so far.
What am I missing here?

Comment: How would you get to know how is the device sending data? Also, their tool would know their working, so, it works. You should check their API, if any, to communicate properly with the device.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, don't be confused with the device. Before going down to that road, I have studied the requirements from the manufacturer. Even some other third party UDP broadcasting tools are working OK as long as I send to port 1500 and use the exact payload. So, this should be my fault somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket always has a dedicated port. Passing an `IPEndPoint` with port number 0 doesn't mean that you receive packets send to any port. Instead you are binding to a port assigned by the underlying service provider.

```
udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
```

> If you do not care which local port is used, you can create an IPEndPoint using 0 for the port number. In this case, the service provider will assign an available port number between 1024 and 5000

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to use

```
udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1500));
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, you're right about it. In fact that, I avoided from this since I am using sender in the same application. When I assigned the same port as I use with the sender socket, application complains about that. Because, we can't use existing port again for another task. This communication is connection-less communication. So, no open and close, at least what I understand from this. So, if the receive part allocates port 1500, I can't use it for sender which I have to :(

Comment: You need to use either the same UdpClient object or the same Socket object for both sending and receiving.

Comment: Yes, that's it. It was the only way, it works beautifully now. Thanks a lot.